# How can I refactor multiple if…elses in order to be more efficient?

Tags: javascript, function, refactoring

I have an application that calculates fees based on the cartTotal amount.
It will catch modifications on total amount by making use of `[MutationObserver][1]`.
When the total is changed a different fee should be applied based on 2 arrays: 1 for carttotal steps and corresponding fees.

I would like to be more efficient and avoid using all these `else if` statements. Should I use a function being called when a change is observed in the `MutationObserver`? Can I make use of `firstIndex`efficiently?

```
var fees = ["10","20","30"];
var steps = ["99.90","1200.00","3600.00"];
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
var cartTotal = parseFloat($('.total').html())
//apply different fee based on cart total
if (cartTotal <= 0) {
  shippingFee = 0;
} else if (cartTotal > 0 && cartTotal <= steps[0]) {
  shippingFee = fees[0];
} else if (cartTotal > steps[0] && cartTotal <= steps[1]) {
  shippingFee = fees[1];
} else if (cartTotal > steps[1] && cartTotal <= steps[2]) {
  shippingFee = fees[2];
} else if (cartTotal > steps[2] && cartTotal <= steps[3]) {
  shippingFee = fees[3];
} else if (cartTotal > steps[3] && cartTotal <= steps[4]) {
  shippingFee = fees[4];
} else if (cartTotal > steps[4] && cartTotal <= steps[5]) {
  shippingFee = fees[5];
} else {
  shippingFee = fees[6];
}
shippingFee = parseFloat(shippingFee);

observer.observe(changetotal, {
  childList: true
  });
 });
```

Comment: More efficient in terms of bulk of code, or the speed of the code?

Comment: Bulk of code I would say. I would like to avoid all those else ifs… I thought I could use firstIndex(); but I'm not sure how…

Comment: Wait, yeah sorry - I misread it. It's checking between `steps` but will actually choose the value from `fees`.

Comment: Your arrays only have the first three indexes filled, but you reference many more in the `if-else` blocks. Should `fees` go up by 10 for each index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and a nested ternary.

```
var index = steps.findIndex(v => v <= cartTotal),
    shippingFee = cartTotal <= 0
        ? 0
        : index === -1
            ? fees[6]
            : fees[index];
```

Comment: Should be `var index = steps.findIndex(v => v >= cartTotal)` and `fees[fees.lenght-1]` works better for me instead of `fees[6]`. 
Thanks! You did point me in the right direction indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how some of the conditions are redundant -- your if-elseifs are equivalent to:

```
if (cartTotal <= 0) {
  shippingFee = 0;
} else if (cartTotal <= steps[0]) {
  shippingFee = fees[0];
} else if (cartTotal <= steps[1]) {
  shippingFee = fees[1];
} else if (cartTotal <= steps[2]) {
  shippingFee = fees[2];
} else if (cartTotal <= steps[3]) {
  shippingFee = fees[3];
} else if (cartTotal <= steps[4]) {
  shippingFee = fees[4];
} else if (cartTotal <= steps[5]) {
  shippingFee = fees[5];
} else {
  shippingFee = fees[6];
}
```

You can roll it into a loop:

```
if (cartTotal <= 0) {
  shippingFee = 0;
} else if (cartTotal <= steps[5]) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (cartTotal <= steps[i]) {
      shippingFee = fees[i];
      break;
    }
  }
} else {
  shippingFee = fees[6];
}
```

You can even make it shorter by including the zeroes at the start of `steps` and `fees`.

I also recommend not hardcoding the value `5` in the for-loop, but basing it on the size of your arrays.